# How to use 'slice' to get just a part of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to get a part of an array that I already have dynamically. I want to divide this array in two part. I have got the first half part of array with slice method but I cant get the second half part. 
Thank you in advance!

```
This is how I took the first part of the array

 var arrayOne = []
 arrayOne = array.d.slice(0, array.d.length / 2);    
                     console.log(arrayOne );
```

Comment: What is `array.d`?

Comment: `array.d.slice(array.d.length / 2)`;

Comment: If I have this array [ 12, 15, 2 , 67, 56, 98 ] , the firstArray must be [ 12, 15, 2] and the secondArray [ 67, 56 ,98]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dear you can get similer half by your method.

Have a look at this code,

`arrayTwo = array.d.slice(array.d.length / 2, array.d.length);

console.log(arrayTwo );`

Answer (score 0):

You need to take an integer value and slice from the second half.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    first = array.slice(0, Math.floor(array.length / 2)),
    second = array.slice(Math.floor(array.length / 2));

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```